# 3rd person game with rigid body

Tags: unity, rigid-body-dynamics

Im making a 3rd person 3D game. I have a little capsule shaped player controlled drone at the moment that moves on a flat surface. Y axis is locked. The Game object contains a script and then the child objects which are the actual body parts. If i attach a rigidbidy to the root object i get crazy results. The drone collides with something and starts to spin and then forward becomes some upward direction.

Somehow i would like to be able to use the pysics collision and ragdoll effects but still be able to maintain the keyboard movement. I guess that id have to animate the drone getting back up again when fallen.

Movement code

```
    void CheckForKeys ()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {          
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * walkingSpeed);           
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {          
        transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * walkingSpeed);          
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {          
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotatingSpeed);          
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {          
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime * rotatingSpeed);
```

Comment: You could, rather than just translating the object, apply a force to it instead. That should remove *some* of the issues with the RigidBody.

Comment: I think you must have problems with your colliders. Which objects have colliders in your drone object hierarchy? If the root and child objects have colliders that intersect from the beginning, the physics can present weird behavior.

Comment: @dsilva.vinicius yes this is definitly what happened. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the root and child colliders intersect from the beginning the physics can present weird behaviour.